# How to send a text message from Django API in the response body to a React function at client end?

Tags: python, reactjs, django

My requirement is to send a piece of JSON code from my React function to a Django server at the backend. The Django API will process the code and send a message if any error is found during processing or nothing (blank response).

I am trying with the following piece of code, however not able to capture the response text in React API sent from Django API.

The React API code looks as below: 
I could not find anything sent from the Django API in the body of the response object as it's coming as null.

```
class Counter extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        code: {"name": "simon"}
    };
   
    this.sendCode = this.sendCode.bind(this);
} 
  sendCode(code) {
        let url = "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/sendcode?code="+ encodeURIComponent(code);
        fetch(url, {
            method:'GET',
            mode: 'no-cors',
            // body: JSON.stringify(code)
        }).then(function(response) {
            console.log("Response = ", response);
        }); 

    }

    render() { 
        return (
        <React.Fragment>
            <button onClick={ ()=> this.sendCode(this.state.code)}className='btn btn-secondary btn-sm'>Send JSON code</button>
            
        </React.Fragment>
        );
    }
}
```

The Django code looks as below:

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path("api/sendcode/", views.response_back, name='response_back')
]
```

views.py 
Initially tried to send a JSON code back as response, getting no success, just trying to send a simple text message.

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
import json

def response_back(request):
    json_code = request.GET["code"]
    print("json code = ", json_code)
    # return HttpResponse(json.dumps({
    #     "formdata": {"error": "some error occured"},
    # }),
    #     content_type="application/json"
    # )

    return HttpResponse("some error occured", content_type='text/plain')
```

How can I send a text message (or a JSON object) from the Django API to the React client API and capture it ?

Thanks

Comment: If I copy paste the URL on the browser or in postman it's returning the text. however in the react code not able to capture it. please help.

Comment: Why are you setting the mode of the fetch request to `no-cors`? This prevents you from reading the response

Comment: Otherwise the Access control allow origin error is causing the problem, pls suggest a way around

Comment: Fix the CORS issue, this package may help https://pypi.org/project/django-cors-headers/

Comment: it solved the issue